# Android change UI from adapter

Tags: android, performance

In my activity I have one recyclerview and each item view contains buttons. I want to be able to change some UI elements and other things such as an Array of custom objects for the adapter itself in my activity from the recyclerview adapter. Until now  I declared the needed views as static but I found out that it's a terrible practice.

Example: I have the following recyclerview that represents a cart filled with a custom viewholder, from an Array of custom "cart_product" objects. (One of this custom oject's proprieties is "quantity" - represented by the spinner). I want to be able to change the object's "quantity" property by changing the spinner's value from the adapter... How could this be done? And when all the products are removed from cart (by swiping & detected from adapter) I want to display a textvie

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdGit.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a minimal, complete, reproducible example so that we can help you with your problem. See here on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use callbacks:

In adapter create an interface:

```
public interface EventHandler {
    void handle(int position) // if u need know position. If no, just create method without params
}
```

Create an private instance of interface in adapter:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourHolder> {
    private EventHanlder handler;
}
```

Implement `EventHanlder` in activity:

```
public class Mainacitivity extends Activity implements YourAdapter.EventHandler {
//.....
    @Override
    void handle (int position) {
        // TODO do whatever u want
    }
}
```

Add `EventHandler` to constructor parameters:

```
public YourAdapter (List<YourObject> data, EventHandler handler) {
    //....
    this.handler = handler;
}
```

When you need to change UI call

```
handler.hanlde(position);
```

And, finally pass `this` when initializing adapter

```
adapter = new YourAdapter (data, this)
```

If u need something else (not position), just change signature of `handle()` method